How to Activate the cell in a column with the current date in Google Sheets Script?
I am looking for a simple script to press a button or use a drop down to go to the current date. I am new to scripting and this problem is definitely showing that. I already have a menu item created.
I have tried this, but it is not doing anything. I'm not sure what the issue is, whether it is formatting or another issue.:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var ranges = sheet.createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).activate();
}


Was there a error thrown? Could you log ranges(console.log( ranges)) and see executions to see the log?

try:
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  cell.setValue(date);
}

added SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone() to ensure the date is formatted according to the spreadsheet's time zone
if you prefer GMT within script use:
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  cell.setValue(date);
}


update
to jump to current day when dates on active sheet are in A column use:
function jumpToToday() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the current date and set hours to 0 to compare dates only (without time)
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  // Get all values in column A
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // Loop through the values to find today's date
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var cellDate = values[i][0];
    
    // Check if the cell contains a date and if it matches today's date
    if (cellDate instanceof Date) {
      cellDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      if (cellDate.getTime() === today.getTime()) {
        // Activate the cell with today's date and scroll to it
        var targetRange = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1);
        sheet.setActiveRange(targetRange);
        sheet.getActiveRange().activate(); // Ensure the cell is selected
        break;
  }}}}


Column A is filled with linear dates. I am looking for a way to jump to the current date in the array.

@doubleunary indeed. fixed

Try this:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', 'M/d/yyyy');
  var rgA = sh.createTextFinder(date).findAll();
  sh.getRangeList(rgA.map(r => r.getA1Notation())).activate();
}


